# why does the "If GetAsyncKeyState" sends Button infinitely?

Tags: c++, macros, hotkeys

I wanted to make a macro that sends space infinitely only if I press it, the problem is that it's sending it even after I left my finger of the button.

```
DWORD WINAPI BhopThread(LPVOID lp)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (bhop)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
                {
                Sleep(10);
                keybd_event(0x20, 0, 0, 0);
                Sleep(1);
                keybd_event(0x20, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                Sleep(10);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

what did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the most signifcant bit of the return value of the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function to determine if they key is currently pressed or not.

[`GetAsyncKeyState()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies **whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState**. However, you should not rely on this last behavior;

Simply, it means that `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns not just true or false, but a wide range of values. To determine if the key really is currently held down, aka pressed, you need to use a **bit-wise operator** with the value `0x8000`.

Example to check if the <kbd>Space</kbd> key is currently held down:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)
{
    // high bit is set.  Space is currently held down.
}
```

What is a bit-wise operator?

This is too broad to explain in this answer. I recommend you to have some basic C++ books/docs/tutorials to read.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: it's my first hour in c++ and I didn't understand a single sentence that you wrote, could you explain a bit more what I have done wrong and how is it made correctly

Comment: keep up your motivation and do some basic c++ tutorials, also read some books about c++.
btw. see my edit. although your question is to broad to answer - a working fix is provided

Comment: The return value of `GetAsyncKeyState()` is a `signed short`, and the high bit is the sign bit, so you can alternatively use `if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) < 0)` instead. A signed value is negative when its sign bit is 1

Comment: @Kierak That answer **is very clear**.  It would not be possible to make a better answer as it is perfect as it.